# Why does a ~0.5MB binary file take up 4.3MB of iCloud space when stored in a Core Data record?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

**The situation**

I am using Core Data's "Allows External Storage" to store compressed images and small audio files in Core Data. Performance benchmarks have shown that this is actually quite performant. Also, I am using Core Data's PersistentCloudKitContainer to sync my database with iCloud.

"Allows External storage" will automatically save files that are bigger than ~500KB (?) to the file system and only store a reference in the database. This works nicely. For instance, a 1MB image file is stored as an external record and takes up the expected 1MB of iCloud storage after syncing. Also, files that are smaller than those ~500KB are not stored as external record (ckAsset), but as binaryData in the database record.

**The problem:**

For some reason a 0.47MB binary data file that is stored directly in the database will take up about 4.3MB of iCloud storage. That is 9x of the expected amount. Inspecting the binary data stored in the record shows that the binary data itself has the expected size of only 0.47MB (CloudKit Dashboard). Also, I have verified that the local app bundle only grows by the expected 0.47MB. Thus, how can those additional 3.8MB of consumed iCloud storage be explained? In contrast, audio and image files that are larger than ~500KB are stored as external records and take up the correct amount of iCloud storage.

Please look at this annotated image for a better understanding:
[Image that illustrates the problem (CloudKit Dashboard)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWU92.jpg)

**Ideas / Workarounds / What I tried:**

- I could try to find a way to always store files as ckAssets/external records. (e.g. by lowering the limit for storing ckAssets to 0.01MB). If that is possible.
- Could the Write-Ahead-Log (WAL) of SQLite be involved in creating huge temporary sqlite-wal files? I tried limiting the WAL journal size and the local sqlite-wal is small,  so I don't think that this is where the problem lies. Unless there is an independent iCloud WAL file that I don't know about.

I would be glad if anyone could help me with this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is iCloud perhaps retaining past versions of the file?

Comment: Good idea. However, the 500KB image instantly consumes 4.3MB after upload. Thus, I doubt that any additional past versions exist.

Comment: Can you test with one smaller and one bigger file? If both new files are same size on  the cloud- then you got your answer. p.s. I have no idea what iCloud is :)

Comment: @Gergo Thanks for your comment. The storage that is consumed on the cloud is always about 7-9 times as high as the actual file size. So it is not always the same size on the cloud.

Comment: Where you you see the 4.3MB size? It's not in your image.

Comment: @TomHarrington In the device's settings under "iCloud > Manage storage". The app's iCloud container size instantly increases by 4.3MB. Deleting the image decreases the container size by exactly that amount. This can be reproduced with any image < ~500KB.